# Unable to override osrf/ros entrypoint

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, docker, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

This is my first post and I'm very confusing about ROS + docker.
What i want to do is to override `osrf/ros` entrypoints.

The entrypoint's difference is just added to source my workspace's `setup.bash`.
This is my `entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

# setup ros environment
source "/opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash"
source "/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash"

exec "$@"
```

And I modified `Dockerfile` to create workspace and build package.
This is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM osrf/ros:kinetic-desktop-full

# For Nvidia GPU
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES ${NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES:-all}
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES ${NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES:+$NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES,}graphics
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libxext-dev libx11-dev x11proto-gl-dev dh-autoreconf\
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/ \
    && git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/libglvnd && cd libglvnd \\
    && ./autogen.sh && ./configure && make -j4 && make install

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    ros-kinetic-ridgeback-* \
    && mkdir -p /catkin_ws/src && cd /catkin_ws/src \
    && . /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.sh \
    && git clone https://github.com/ridgeback/ridgeback_robot \
    && rosdep install --from-path . -r -y --ignore-src \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/ \
    && cd /catkin_ws && catkin_make

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["bash"]
```

Then, I run `docker run -it <myimage>`, docker container shutdown immediately.
However, If i removed `source "/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`, container will start. So i think `/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` is a problem, but I don't know how to solve it because if i run `docker logs <containerID> --details`, no logs appeared.

Could someone help me?

I use Ubuntu:18.04 and melodic is installed in my local environment.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320375/unable-to-override-osrf/ros-entrypoint/) by [arwtyxouymz](https://answers.ros.org/users/40735/arwtyxouymz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-04-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The immediate shutdown is coming from the `set -e` [flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19622569) in the entrypoint. I'm not sure what the problem with the develspace setup script is, but it happens on both the docker image you sent and the main workspace I'm using for my projects, so the error seems to be pretty pervasive. If someone knows how to error trace a bash script that would be helpful for debugging further, but you can get started by removing the `set -e`.

---

Originally posted by [Andrew Price](https://answers.ros.org/users/3629/andrew-price/) with karma: 66 on 2019-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arwtyxouymz](https://answers.ros.org/users/40735/arwtyxouymz/) on 2019-04-06**:
Thank you Andrew!

I removed `set -e` flag, and succeeded to run a container.
But with `docker-compose`, ros cannot find my local package.
This is my `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '2.3'

services:
  base:
    build: .
    container_name: base
    runtime: nvidia
    privileged: true
    environment:
      - "ROS_HOSTNAME=base"
      - "ROS_MASTER_URI=http://master:11311"
      - "DISPLAY=${DISPLAY}"
      - "QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1"
    volumes:
      - "/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw"
    command: rospack find ridgeback_base
```

If i executed `docker-compose up`, base container exited with status code 1 without flag `set -e` in my entrypoint.
However, `docker run -it --rm <image name> rospack find ridgeback_base` is fine.

What's wrong?

**Comment by [Andrew Price](https://answers.ros.org/users/3629/andrew-price/) on 2019-04-08**:
@arwtyxouymz, that's probably best for another question, and I'm not super familiar with `docker-compose`. On my machine, running

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t ros_answer .
docker run --rm -it ros_answer:latest rospack find ridgeback_base
```

returns

```
/catkin_ws/src/ridgeback_robot/ridgeback_base
```